# Will Kaspersky or BitDefender work on Hyper-V?

Tags: antivirus, virtualization

In case if I decide to test them or just don't want install them on a physical machine. I mean usual versions of antiviruses, not specially designed for virtual machines. Also interesting if I can scan files which are in shared folder.

Comment: "can I run X?" is an undefined question

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to. While commercial AV software digs fairly deep into Windows, it generally doesn't rely on any behavior that differs between VMs and bare hardware. It's reasonably common practice to run AV on VMs. The only reason it wouldn't work is if the AV software specifically tested whether it was running on a VM and refused to execute if so, and I don't know of any such checks (or any good reason for them to exist) in either product you mention.

Files on shared folders can be scanned, just as any readable file can, but continuous monitoring is probably not possible. AV software implements continuous monitoring by hooking into the file system. Shared folders are not part of the VM's file system, at least not the same way as the VM's own virtual drives are (they're more equivalent to mapped network drives), so the VM will not, for example, see the file system functions uses to add a file to a shared folder.